# How to merge duplicated rows

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

I have a data frame that looks like

| Nicknames | Names |
| --- | --- |
| Fonse, Fons | Alfons |
| Fonse, Fonsi | Alfons |
| Gustel, Gustl, Guste, | August |
| Baldi | Balthasar |
| Hausl, Baldi | Balthasar |
| Flore, Flori | Florian |

I would like to merge the duplicated rows to be :

| Nicknames | Names |
| --- | --- |
| Fonse, Fons,Fonse, Fonsi | Alfons |
| Gustel, Gustl, Guste, | August |
| Baldi, Hausl, Baldi | Balthasar |
| Flore, Flori | Florian |

I was able to creat a subset of the duplicate but I don't know how to combine them

```
nick2 <- subset(nick, any(duplicated(nick$Names)))
```

Here is the data as a csv file
https://github.com/Garybertrand/nick

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

setDT(df)[, list(Nicknames = paste(Nicknames, collapse = ', ')), 
          by = c('Names')] %>%
  select(Nicknames,Names)
```

Comment: Why the `%>% and select`? If you return `Nicknames` within each group of `Names` then you already have those two variables selected.

Comment: The select was used for the purpose of reordering the columns, without the select part ```Names``` will would be the first column. This is unnecessary if the order of the columns do not matter. I just thought that the final output should have the columns in the same order as the original df.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use base R.

```
aggregate(Nicknames ~ Names, unique(df), paste, collapse = ", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

The short `tidyverse` solution would be like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Names) %>% 
  summarize(Nicknames = paste0(Nicknames, collapse = ", "))
```